# Variable booleana de input no funciona (ANGULAR)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angular

buenas, tengo un problema a ver si ustedes me lo pueden resolver.

Tengo un componente padre con un componente hijo. El componente padre tiene un pequeño menú para cambiar idioma. Simplemente usa una variable booleana, y cuando en el app component (padre) cambio el valor de la variable los ngif funcionan perfectamente:

App componente TS

```
  public euskera: boolean;


  constructor(){
    this.euskera=false;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  setEuskera(){
    this.euskera=true;
  }

  setCastellano(){
    this.euskera=false;
  }
```

App componente HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  <header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logoSoinuka.png">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
  
          <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']"><a>hasiera</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/sobre-nosotros']"><a>nor gara?</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/proximos-eventos']"><a>hurrengo ekitaldiak</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/contacto']"><a>kontaktua</a></li>
          <li (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()"><a>Hizkuntza:<span>[</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  
      </nav>
  
  
  </header>

  <div id="language" (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()">
    <ul>
  
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setCastellano()"><a>Gaztelania</a></li>
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setEuskera()"><a>Euskara</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="true"></app-home>
  </div>
  
</div>


<div *ngIf="euskera==false">
  <header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logoSoinuka.png">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
  
          <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']"><a>Inicio</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/sobre-nosotros']"><a>¿Quienes somos?</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/proximos-eventos']"><a>Proximos eventos</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/contacto']"><a>Contacto</a></li>
          <li (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()"><a>Lenguaje:<span>[</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  
      </nav>
  
  
  </header>

  <div id="language" (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()">
    <ul>
  
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setCastellano()"><a>Castellano</a></li>
      <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']" (click)="setEuskera()"><a>Euskera</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="false"></app-home>
  </div>
</div>




<body>
  <div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </div>
</body>
```

Hasta aquí como os dije, todo perfecto, todo funciona.

El problema es cuando hago el input de la variable booleana desde un hijo.

Home Component (child)

```
  @Input() euskera:boolean=false;
```

Home component HTML

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  euskk
</div>

<div *ngIf="!euskera">
dd
</div>
```

Al yo hacer esto, no funciona. Solo como false/undefined, pero nunca como true. Por muchas veces que cambie el valor de la variable nunca muestra el texto como True.

Cuando hago un console.log del valor de la variable del input nada más arrancar me marca false (el valor default) Luego si pulso los botones para modificar su valor, por consola me marca el valor real, ya sea true o false, pero los textos jamás me los modifica. Solo queda el de false. Nunca muestra el de true.

¿Qué me estoy dejando? ¿Hay algo que no haya hecho bien?

Espero que me ayuden, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver el problema se puede usar un servicio el cual será el punto central donde se guardará la configuración del idioma para que todos los componentes lo busquen ahí:

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class IdiomaService {

  // variable de tipo EventEmitter que servirá para avisar a los
  // suscriptores que el idioma ha sido cambiado
  private euskera = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  setIdioma(euskera : boolean){
    this.euskera.emit(euskera);
  }
  
  getIdioma(){
    return this.euskera;
  }

}
```

Para que un componente reaccione al cambio de idioma debe recibir una instancia de ese servicio y suscribirse al método `getIdioma()`

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { IdiomaService } from '../idioma.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `<div *ngIf="euskera">
                  euskk
              </div>

            <div *ngIf="!euskera">
                dd
            </div>`
})
export class HomeComponent {
  @Input()
  euskera: boolean = false;

  constructor(service : IdiomaService) { 
    // suscripcion al servicio, cuando se cambie el idioma se emitirá
    // un valor que se guardará en la variable euskera
    service.getIdioma().subscribe( (e: boolean) => this.euskera = e);
  }

 
}
```

Para cambiar el idioma se usa el método `setIdioma(boolean)` del servicio

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IdiomaService } from './idioma.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  {

  euskera : boolean;

 // se recibe una instancia del servicio de idioma que se usará
 // para cambiar el idioma en la app
  constructor(private service : IdiomaService){
    this.euskera = false;

    this.service.setIdioma(this.euskera);
  }
  

  setEuskera(){
    this.euskera=true;

    // llamar al método setIdioma para cambiar el idioma de la app
    this.service.setIdioma(this.euskera);
  }

  setCastellano(){
    this.euskera=false;

    this.service.setIdioma(this.euskera);
  }
}
```

De esa forma, donde sea que se llame el método `setIdioma(boolean)` todos los componentes que estén suscritos al método `getIdioma()` van a recibir el idioma seleccionado.

**No olvidar agregar el servicio en la sección de providers del app.module**

[Código Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u4dp5v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

Comment: Hola, antes de nada, muchas gracias por comentar. Lo he intentado, pero me sigue sin funciona. Al yo pasarle la variable al componente hijo, lo hacia de esta manera:

Comment: <div *ngIf="!euskera">

 <div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="false"></app-home>
 </div>

 
</div>



<div *ngIf="euskera">

 <div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="true"></app-home>
 </div>

 
</div>

Comment: Deberia meter el <app-home [euskera]="euskera"> dentro de cada uno de los ngIf? o simplemente fuera del condicional? Lo he probado de ambas maneras pero me sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: He revisado y probado tu código así como está y la verdad debería funcionar. Si continúas sin encontrar el por qué no funciona puedes compartirme el proyecto completo para probarlo y ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @Lobos, ya he encontrado el error. Y es que no puedo pasar una variable al child ya que estoy mostrando un router-outlet y necesito pasarlo por ahi. ¿Me ayudarías con ese team? Muchas gracias

Comment: Ya agregué un ejemplo usando servicios.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Lobos, muchisimas gracias por la respuesta. He estado intentar aplicar el servicio pero tengo un par de dudas. La primera duda es por qué en el app-home (child) pones un template en lugar del templateUrl (Supongo que es el codigo HTML a cambiar y ya está, ¿no?) Y la segunda duda es, que por algún motivo no me termina de funcionar. No sé si es que haya puesto algo mal. Muchas gracias por todo, amigo

Comment: Sí, solo hay que separar el html a su archivo, lo puse como plantilla  para no tener 2 archivos. Agregué un ejemplo en vivo para que veas el código funcionando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al fin pude resolverlo. Muchas gracias de veras. Ahora solo me falta averiguar como hacer que al cambiar entre componentes, si tiene seteado el idioma euskera no me muestre los textos en español.